# Some JPEGs not displaying correctly / Size limitation

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, jpeg, windows-phone-7.1

I have an app where I download jpegs from Web, decode them and display it on Windows Phone 7.1. It works well, except for one single jpeg file. I tried the app with hundreds of jpegs and this problem occurs rarely.

BTW, I tried decoding jpegs with PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg and ImageTools' Jpeg decoder. Both yielded the same result. %60 or %70 of the picture appears as black and the rest is normal.

Note: It's not a 2000 px limit problem. I solved that by splitting images into several pieces after I decode them.

Another Note: I checked pixel values of those black areas and they are not 0 (the initial value).

Another Note2: Using `<image>` control in XAML and setting its source to the URL below works. But that's not an option for me as I need to split it into several pieces (because of 2000 px problem).

Here is a jpeg I'm having problem with: http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/1840288_700b_v1.jpg

UPDATE: After I decoded that JPEG, I encoded it again and saved it to the Isolated Local Storage and grabbed that file using Isolated Storage Explorer Tool. I could display the image thus it was decoded and encoded properly. I'm still invastigating the issue.

Comment: I tried reading the image with my jpeg decoder and it decodes fine. The only thing notable is that it is a progressive jpeg. Have you tried to read the same image stored as a baseline jpeg? It could be a bug in the progressive jpeg decoder of WP7.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked some other photos that work with my decoder and they are all progressive. I started to think that it might not be a decoder problem, I'm still investigating. I'll update this post if I find an answer.

Comment: @mostruash, move the answer to an answer post and mark it as answer, to help people with similar issues concentrate in the answer part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem Solved: Reason not found

I solved the problem by decreasing the max height of my images. As Windows Phone 7 is limited by 2000 px x 2000 px, I was splitting my images accordingly. It worked for hundreds of images except few (1 in 100). And no, it was not a floating number rounding problem, all pieces had height of max. 2000 pixels. Now I decreased that max number from 2000 to below 1800 and it works. However why this happens is still a mystery to me.

Comment: This is probably due to the OS preventing apps from using too much RAM. a 2000x2000 color image will be stored internally as RGB32 and take 16MB of RAM. A pretty sad limitation since images from the internal camera are larger than that.

Comment: It was not due to a limitation applied to the whole app as I tried using much more RAM than a single 500x7500 image uses. And RAM limitation doesn't explain why splitting into smaller pieces work (Splitted pieces are displayed in the same ScrollViewer simultaneously).

Comment: I believe the limit is 2048x2048 for any single image in Windows Phone 7.1.  I can't see why splitting would fail on 1 in 100, but then work if the size is reduced further.  My guess would be along the same lines as BitBank in that this is down to memory or texture buffer limits somewhere.